# Parsing XML using jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse the XML response from a GET request made from jQuery.
The problem seems to be the type of the XML element that I am interested in.

Please let me know how I can parse this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://purl.org/atom/app#"
xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VVoO9cdk5Eo</id>
<published>2015-04-03T18:30:00.000Z</published>
<updated>2015-04-06T02:11:57.000Z</updated>
<gd:rating average="4.9371624" max="5" min="1" numRaters="2037"
    rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall" />
<yt:statistics favoriteCount="0" viewCount="148847" />
```

With my code, I can successfully retrieve something like 'published'. But I need to parse 'gd:rating'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "xml",
         url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VVoO9cdk5Eo?v=1",
         success: function(response){    
            console.log("Success");    
            var rating = $(response).find('published').first().text();
            alert("#" + rating);           
            }
     });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's XML parsing capabilities are not so great, especially when it comes to namespaces.

You can work around this easily by using standard DOM methods.

```
$(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function () {
        var videoInfo = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VVoO9cdk5Eo?v=1";
        $.get(videoInfo).done(function (xml) {
            var rating = xml.getElementsByTagName("rating")[0];
            if (rating) {
                alert("Average rating: " + rating.getAttribute("average"));
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, no rating.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```